# Run script (.ipynb) that is out the folder of a jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Im trying to run a script (.ipynb) in a jupyter notebook, but this script is in a different folder from the original jupyter notebook. I would like to execute: 
`%run Scripts/python/script.ipynb`  
The folder **Scripts** is out the folder of the jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 0):

just copy paste file on jupyter root directory in my case it is Users/{user-name}/,